# Socket recv() receives only 1 byte of data

Tags: c, macos, sockets, network-programming

I was trying to send `"-1"` as an indicator from the server to the client using `send()` function, however the `recv()` function at the client side keeps receiving only 1 byte of the data (the return of `recv()` is 1).

#### **Code**

Server-side:

`get_fd(buf, fd, stat_buf)` gets a file descriptor based on the number in `buf` and returns `-1` if the number in `buf` is invalid `0` if everything works fine.

```cpp
if(get_fd(buf, fd, stat_buf) == -1){    // invalid file number
    printf("client has given an invalid file number\n\n");
    if(send(new_sockfd, "-1", 3, 0) == -1){
        perror("client: send");
    }

    close(new_sockfd);
    exit(1);

} else {    // valid file number
    /* code */
}
```

When I entered an invalid file number at the client-side, the `printf()` on the second line works fine and no `perror()` message has been seen.

Client-side:

```cpp
std::memset(&buf, 0, MAXDATASIZE);    // clear the buffer for it has been used previously
if((numbyte = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0))==-1){
    perror("client: recv");
    exit(1);
}

buf[numbyte] = '\0';
printf("numbyte: %d, received: %s\n\n", numbyte, buf);
```

The `numbyte` is always 1, while `printf()` prints nothing for the `buf` as `string`, but when printing the `buf` as an `int` (`%d`) it prints a nonsense negative number, for example `-333179216`.

Comment: It cannot receive only one bit of data, it always reads full bytes.

Comment: Your client isn't sending 16 bytes it's sending 2 bytes. You're also not doing any error checking and haven't posted the full code so I can't see exactly what the problem is

Comment: Your server code is calling `send()` with a three-character-long string but you're telling it to send 16...

Comment: Hi @Akali thank you for your advice. I've tried to change the size to 2 or 3 and it won't fix the problem. I added more details of my server-side code, hope it can better demostrate the problem here. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Shawn thank you for your advice. I've tried to change the size to 2 or 3 and it won't fix the problem. I added more details of my server-side code, hope it can better demostrate the problem here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was at the beginning of the connection when the server sends ( `send()` ) the first message to the client. You set the `len` to a number that is much larger than its actual length. It works fine in the beginning because there are no more communications, but the problem will appear when you try to `send()` through that socket again.

Code (integrity matters):

```cpp
if(send(new_sockfd, "some words here...", 65535, 0) == -1){
    perror("server: send");
}
```